# Can't view databases on secodary node on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-compass

I have just deployed a mongodb and inserted  some data to a new db. I can see the database on MongoDB compass when connecting to the primary with MongoDB Compass but can't view it on secondary node.

It seems there is no replication lags on the secondary nodes.

```
rs.printSecondaryReplicationInfo()
    source: node2:27017
    { syncedTo: 'Sun Oct 23 2022 12:20:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
      replLag: '0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary ' }
    source: node3:27017
    { syncedTo: 'Sun Oct 23 2022 12:20:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
      replLag: '0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary ' }
```

Primary node:

[image]

Secondary node:
[image]

Edited:

I just spotted the problem. This is happening only when you set `readPreference` to `primary` but it doesn't happen with `primaryPreferred`. Do you know what that would be?

mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primaryPreferred&directConnection=true&ssl=false